# connect and arcwise-connect in locally convex space

Tags: connectedness, locally-convex-spaces

Let X be [a locally convex vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_convex_topological_vector_space) and let G be an open connected subnet of X.

How to show that G is [arcwise-connected](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Arcwise-Connected.html)?

I only can show that G is path-connected but do not know why G is arcwise-connected.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How have you shown $G$ is path-connected?

Comment: Is $X$ locally arcwise-connected?

Comment: @Gustavo.This is an exercise in Conway's <Functional analysis>. I think we can get X is locally arcwise-connected since every $x\in X$ has a neighbourhood $x+V$ in which $V$ is an open balanced neighbourhood of  0.

Comment: @jdc.I only need to show that every path-connected component W of G is open subset. and this can be proved by noticing that for every $x\in W$, there is an balanced open neighbourhood $V_x$of 0 such that $x+V_x \subset$ G.  and every point of $x+V_x $ can be connected with x by a path. then $x+V_x \subset W$ and W is open.